# Run some task in parallel and others sequentially using python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing, future

I was new to python, Now, I have an requirements to run single function as parallel for some process and some may be depends on others.
My dataset will be like:

```
[
  {
    'process_id': 1,
    'dependency_id': 0
  },
  {
    'process_id': 2,
    'dependency_id': 0
  },
  {
    'process_id': 3,
    'dependency_id': 0
  },
  {
    'process_id': 4,
    'dependency_id': 2
  },
  {
    'process_id': 5,
    'dependency_id': 2
  },
  {
    'process_id': 6,
    'dependency_id': 1
  }
]
```

Here,

> the process_id 1,2,3 should run in parallel because it has the
>   dependency_id as 0.
>
> the process_id 4 has the dependency_id as 2 -- it should wait until
>   process 2 get done
>
> the process_id 5 has the dependency_id as 2 -- it should wait until
>   process 2 get done. Now process 4 and 5 should wait for 2 and get run
>   in parallel.
>
> the process_id 6 has the dependency_id as 1 -- it should wait until
>   process 1 get done

I have tried in the following way :

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep

process = []
process_list =[{'process_id': 1,'dependency_id': 0},{'process_id': 2,'dependency_id': 0},{'process_id': 3,'dependency_id': 0},{'process_id': 4,'dependency_id': 2},{'process_id': 5,'dependency_id': 2},{'process_id': 6,'dependency_id': 1}]

def process_fn(process_id):
    print i

def main():
  for item in len(process_list):
     p = process(target=process_fn, args=(item['process_id']))
     process.append(p)
     p.start()
```

But I want to know how to include that dependency logic inside multiprocessing. Can anyone please help me with the solution.